# Splitting 24 hours into 96 equal 15 minute intervals in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with A Time interval (24 Hours) and a volume (INT) I need to show this in 15 minute intervals (Total time for day would be 96 intervals).  Here is a table with a sample of what I have:

```
CREATE TABLE #temptable ( [INTERVAL] nvarchar(3), [Volume] decimal(16,4) )
INSERT INTO #temptable
VALUES
( N'001', 1.2000 ), 
( N'002', 1.2000 ), 
( N'003', 1.2000 ), 
( N'004', 1.7000 ), 
( N'005', 1.9000 ), 
( N'006', 1.9000 ), 
( N'007', 1.8000 ), 
( N'008', 1.9000 ), 
( N'009', 2.2000 ), 
( N'010', 1.8000 ), 
( N'011', 2.0000 ), 
( N'012', 1.7000 ), 
( N'013', 1.5000 ), 
( N'014', 1.5000 ), 
( N'015', 1.3000 ), 
( N'016', 1.6000 ), 
( N'017', 1.7000 ), 
( N'018', 2.0000 ), 
( N'019', 2.0000 ), 
( N'020', 2.2000 ), 
( N'021', 2.0000 ), 
( N'022', 2.2000 ), 
( N'023', 1.9000 ), 
( N'024', 1.4000 )
DROP TABLE #temptable
```

I honestly have no idea where to start, But Need to have Interval 1 through 4 equal to the current interval (1.2000) /4 (.3) in this case.  The total number of intervals would be 96 since I am breaking this down to 15 min intervals.

I am looking for a starting point. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using a cross join to bring in the 15 minute intervals:

```
WITH minutes AS (
    SELECT 0 AS minute UNION ALL
    SELECT 15 UNION ALL
    SELECT 30 UNION ALL
    SELECT 45
)

SELECT
    t.[INTERVAL] + ':' + RIGHT('00' + CAST(m.minute AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) AS time,
    t.[Volume] / 4.0 AS [Volume]
FROM #temptable t
CROSS JOIN minutes m
ORDER BY
    t.[INTERVAL],
    m.minute;
```

### Demo

Comment: I like this much better than the answer I came up with:

Comment: tiny "bug", this will return 24:45 as a period. Should the first interval be 00:00 or 00:15?

Comment: I tried to upvote, but it says I must have a 15 or better reputation...

Comment: @DanielN Yes, but that really is a problem in the OP's data.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen maybe a quick dirty fix is to change t.[INTERVAL] to CAST(CAST(t.[INTERVAL] as int)-1 as varchar) then periods will be returned from 00:00 to 23:45